# DevExpress Unbound column event not firing, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have created an unbound column which I intend to populate with calculated data; however, I am unable to get the CustomUnboundColumnData event to fire. I basically copied the code from DevExpress documentation on https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477

As per other posts found I made sure that there are no other columns with the same name.
The new unbound column does indeed appear in the grid, but the event is never firing so I don't know how to populate it.

In my constructor I define the columns as below: (I made sure there are no other columns with the same name)

```
        GridColumn testColumn = new GridColumn();
        testColumn.FieldName = "Test Column1";
        testColumn.VisibleIndex = gridView1.Columns.Count;
        testColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.DateTime;
        // Disable editing.
        testColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
        // Specify format settings.
        testColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
        testColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "d";
        testColumn.Visible = true;
        gridView1.Columns.Add(testColumn);
```

Then I have my event function which never fires

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("unbound column a go go");
```

1. How can I populate the unbound column?

Comment: Can you try adding the column to your gridview before applying the properties to it?

Comment: Thanks @Saragis I had already tried that first by using `testColumn = gridView1.Columns.AddField("Test Column");` as my first line, then adding all of the properties, and got the same result - event never firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to DevExpress support forum (which is very nice by the way)

I was missing the line for `gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData;` which tells the grid which event handler(s) to use for unbound columns